# Japanese text error in Google speech api php

Tags: php, google-speech-api

Google Speech api is working fine for me when I use `'languageCode' => 'en-US'` with English audio file. But when using `'languageCode' => 'ja-JP'` with Japanese audio file, its returning broken text like `"Transcription: ã‚‚ã—ã‚‚ã—è² ã‘ãƒ›ãƒ³ãƒ€ã—ã¦ã‚‚ã—ã‚‚ã—"`

Sample code from google :

```
# Includes the autoloader for libraries installed with composer
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

# Imports the Google Cloud client library
use Google\Cloud\Speech\SpeechClient;

# Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
$projectId = 'YOUR_PROJECT_ID';

# Instantiates a client
$speech = new SpeechClient([
    'projectId' => $projectId,
    'languageCode' => 'en-US',
]);

# The name of the audio file to transcribe
$fileName = __DIR__ . '/resources/audio.raw';

# The audio file's encoding and sample rate
$options = [
    'encoding' => 'LINEAR16',
    'sampleRateHertz' => 16000,
];

# Detects speech in the audio file
$results = $speech->recognize(fopen($fileName, 'r'), $options);

foreach ($results[0]->alternatives() as $alternative) {
    echo 'Transcription: ' . $alternative['transcript'] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

I've checked the
[Cloud Speech API Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-php) and followed the sample from Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Speech API returning the response in Japanese correctly inside `$results`. The Default encoding type is UTF-8. Its clearly written in the documentation. [Google\Cloud\Language\LanguageClient](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.39.2/language/languageclient)

The problem was `echo` in the `foreach` which breaks down the Japanese character. In my case I actually don't need to echo rather than use the `$results`. So now it's working fine for me.

Perhaps, If someone wants to use `echo` to show the result, following links can be helpful.

1. [PHP Japanese echo string becomes question marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006642/php-japanese-echo-string-becomes-question-marks)
2. [How to display Japanese characters on a php page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666987/how-to-display-japanese-characters-on-a-php-page)

Thanks.